# Unable to save form due to Unpermited parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-submit, strong-parameters

The goal is simple, create a document with a name and description an attached CSV file.

I have the following migration:

```
class CreateKeywords < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :keywords do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false, unique: true
      t.string :description, null: false 
      t.string :keys, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :keys, KeywordsUploader

  validates :name, :description, :keys, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: true

end
```

Controller:

```
class KeywordsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @keywords = Keyword.all 
  end

  def new
    @keyword = Keyword.new
  end

  def create
    puts "Keyword params"
    pp keyword_params
    @keyword = Keyword.new(keyword_params)
    if @keyword.save
      flash[:success] = "New server created!"
      redirect_to @keyword
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def keyword_params
    params.permit(:keyword).permit(:name, :description, :keys)
  end 


end
```

And finally view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Create keywords set') %>
<h1>New keywords set</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for @keyword, :html => {:multipart => true } do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>

      <%= f.label :keywords %>
      <%= f.file_field :keys %> 

      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I'm trying to submit a form with all required fields I'm getting the following error in a view:

```
1) Name can't be blank
2) Description can't be blank
3) Keys can't be blank
```

In Rails console I can see the following during the form submission:

```
Started POST "/keywords" for ::1 at 2015-10-09 17:21:40 +0300
Processing by KeywordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QO69fZ9xx1+mXRTL1TqZQLs9kYriQj4sqxV0t8P8XG2nu1FvKmOw6fISpmvi70VlWrD9bCJg7bCqwLwUfvwGRQ==", "keyword"=>{"name"=>"asd", "description"=>"asd"}, "commit"=>"Create keywords"}
Keyword params
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, keyword, commit
{}
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, keyword, commit
```

As you can see, the strong params function returns an empty hash, and
that is why it's impossible to create an instance of a model "Keyword".

What can be a problem?

Comment: why multipart => true? and do you use ActiveAdmin?

Comment: No. I tried to remove this parameter but it seems that it doesn't affect the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!

Instead of using:

```
  def keyword_params
    params.permit(:keyword).permit(:name, :description, :keys)
  end
```

I should been using:

```
 def keyword_params
    params.require(:keyword).permit(:name, :description, :keys)
  end
```

The issue was caused by incorrect keyword_params method.